# Google reverse geocoder doesn't return unincorporated community names

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-geocoding-api

So, there is an "Anthony" small community which showed in GoogleMaps 
https://www.google.com/maps/place/Anthony,+WV+24938,+USA/@37.8959703,-80.3407936,15z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x884c425d36b87e11:0xd99c2e98a2185333?hl=en

My question is - why Google's reverse geocoder doesn't return correct name of that unincorporated community?

For example, if i try to reverse that coordinates 37.895767,-80.330698 which points to the center of "Anthony" it returns "Frankford"-city, which far far away from "Anthony"([see picture](http://joxi.ru/lbrR5MXf4DkjA1)).

[image]

Similar behavior at maps.google.com - when i point near "Anthony" it shows nothing related to it. [See another picture](http://joxi.ru/gkrDl3Vt3qO9rp).

[Hereis JSON](http://joxi.ru/8ZrJY1LFN80nAj) returned from reverse geocoder([json format](http://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer/cb0e0eb7)). And there is no any signs about "Anthony" location. I'm curious...why?

Any thoughts?

P.S. I'm using web-api to obtain reversed geocoded data
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=37.895767,-80.330698&language=en&key=MY_KEY

Answer (score 0):

This may have something to do with rural naming conventions, given that these places belong to "unincorporated" (region of land that is not governed by its own local municipal corporation, but rather is administered as part of larger administrative divisions) criteria. In your JSON data: "formatted_address": "3853 Anthony Rd, Frankford, WV 24938, USA", notice the the type property which is based on locality and political:

```
{
"long_name": "Frankford",
"short_name": "Frankford",
"types": [
"locality",
"political"
]
}
```

This means that Frankford is the recognized locality of Anthony area. There is also a chance that Google Maps are that inaccurate ( it was able to pinpoint the location though) as implied by spherical geometry concepts in [Google Docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry#Geometry).

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the response I can see that reverse geocoding returns '3853 Anthony Rd, Frankford, WV 24938, USA' for 37.895767,-80.330698.

According to USPS.com this is a valid address

https://tools.usps.com/go/ZipLookupResultsAction!input.action?resultMode=1&companyName=&address1=3853+Anthony+Road&address2=&city=Frankford&state=WV&urbanCode=&postalCode=&zip=24938

though '3853 Anthony Rd, Anthony, WV 24938, USA' is also recognized as valid

https://tools.usps.com/go/ZipLookupResultsAction!input.action?resultMode=1&companyName=&address1=3853+Anthony+Rd&address2=&city=Anthony&state=WV&urbanCode=&postalCode=&zip=24938

You can report a data problem to Google following:

https://support.google.com/maps/answer/3094088